# How to make withdrawal system on your website?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether, metamask, web3.py

I am new to web3 and I already made eth deposit using metamask, but now I also want to make withdrawal system, I made an example but I dont think this is so correctly. All this I made in python, using Django. Can someone give me some advice about smart contracts, or help me with this?

```
provider_ulr = QuickNode_goerli

web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(provider_url))

acc_1 = "0xHae8228A429433e8E769276650431939860G634D2"
acc_2 = "0xh32c0d285cfc6e94e3de7d5bde9ea475d4f217e3"

private_key = "***"

nonce = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(acc_1)
chainId= web3.eth.chain_id

tx = {
    'nonce': nonce,
    'to': acc_2,
    'value': web3.toWei(0.001, 'ether'),
    'gas': 21000,
    'gasPrice': web3.eth.gas_price,
    'chainId' : chainId
}

signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, private_key)
tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
print(web3.toHex(tx_hash))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "withdrawal system"? What's the use case? What are the requirements? What's the purpose? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Ismael by withdrawal system, I mean, for example, User made a deposit for $10, bought something on web, after he remains with $7, and he want to send this $7 from my website to his wallet, on website opens the window with address and amount where to send the money, but how to send it?

Comment: If you are using smart contract you could use `<address>.transfer` to withdraw from the contract to `<address>`.

Comment: @Ismael smart contracts are made by Solidity? I just recently started to learn about this. I updated the question, and put the example that I made, but I think I made not the smart contract transaction, just simple